# In which folder to store text files in Google App Engine project and how to retrive them?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to store text on google app engine. In which folder do I need to store them, and how to get the path of the file ?

I have tried storing them in WEB-INF folder and I have tried following path to retrive file:

```
FILE_PATH="/RESTful Jersey App/war/WEB-INF/abc.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access this file anywhere, you put it in the `/war` folder or any subfolder within it. To retrieve it:

```
FILE_PATH="abc.txt"
```

If you want to access this file internally in your server code, you put it in the `WEB-INF` folder. Then you use:

```
FILE_PATH="/WEB-INF/abc.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you can place it anywhere inside your war folder if you wish to make it publicly accessible, if you need that file to be accessible only to your app (eg a PK12 secret file) you need to place it within the `WEB-INF` folder.

I order to actually retrieve it you need to get the real path from your current ServletContext eg:

```
ServletContext context =//your servlet context (either injected into and endpoint or gotten in an actual Servlet.
String path = context.getRealPath("<path starting form the base WAR dir>");
try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(path);
            template = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```